# How to determine the radius when utilizing the disc method

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Lately, I have been struggling to figure out how to determine the radius used in the formula $V=\pi r^2$ when finding the volume of a solid revolving around an axis. From my experience with solving problems in this topic, I believe the radius is always the function in the case of revolving around the x- and y-axis. However, when it comes to revolving around other axes, I believe the radius is subject to adding or subtracting by a constant not included in the function depending on which one will provide the radius. Is this uniform for all cases of finding the volume when revolving around axes other than the $x$- and $y$-axis?

Here is a basic example which I found on Khan Academy to base our conversation on: Let R be the region enclosed by the line $y=1,$ the line $x=4,$ and the curve $y=\sqrt x +1$. A solid is generated by rotating R about the line $y=1.$

To start off, the radius must be found in order to insert it into the volume formula. I know that the function is included in the radius however I am unsure if a constant is subtracted or added.

Answer (score 1):

It will help a lot to draw a picture.  The region being rotated lies above the line $y=1$.  If you imagine a point $(x,y)$ on the curve being rotated, the radius of the circle it traces out will be $y-1$.  I think if you draw a vertical segment from the curve to the line $y=1$ and then imagine somehow twirling the line to make the curve rotate, you will agree that this is obvious.

I would not advise trying to memorize rules to tell you how to figure out the radius.  Sketch a picture.  It doesn't have to be very accurate.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @saulspatz. After completing some practice it seems like this is only applicable to the case of finding the area of a ring but not when determining the area of a solid disk. Is this statement consistent for all cases?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  In the given example, the disks have no holes.

Comment: I am not referring to the given example in my previous comment, rather to the case in which the goal is to find the area of specifically a ring.

Comment: Drawing a picture always works for me.  As I tried to say in my answer, I think these questions are best handled by dealing with each problem on its own, rather than trying to come up with a general method.  If my memory doesn't play me false, $50$ something years ago, when I was taking calculus in high school, I couldn't do these problems until I decided to ignore the methods I'd been taught, and work out each case on my own.  I was never sure which method was applicable until I figured it out myself.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!